# How a cascode GaN can have a low Rds(on)?

Tags: cascode, gan

GaN power device are said to have a lower Rds(ON) than Si MOSFET and according to the picture below there is no doubt about it.

[image]

<sup>Source: [IEMN](https://www.iemn.fr/en/news/iemn-and-epigan-a-record-combination-of-specific-on-resistance-and-breakdown-voltage.html)</sup>

Nevertheless as GaN power devices are particular devices, some GaN power devices are based on cascode configuration with a Si MOSFET as illustrated above:

[image]

What I do not understand is: as there is a Si MOSFET in series with GaN HEMT how the Rds(on) of a GaN cascode power device could be lower than a Si power device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The silicon MOSFET does not need to block much voltage so it can be cheaply made to have an Rds(on) that does not add much to that of the GaN HEMT. For example, a 0.05 ohm compound device might be 0.005 ohm for the MOSFET and 0.045 ohm for the HEMT.

A 650V (say) MOSFET with 0.05 ohm Rds(on) would be require a great deal of silicon acreage.